# Does std::find on empty vector cause undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, std

trying to find an info on what happens if an empty vector used during std::find but didn't had much luck finding any info.

My question is, if an empty vector passed to std::find, is the return value always a nullptr or is it undefined behaviour?

```
  std::vector<int> someDataContainer;
  auto it = std::find(someDataContainer.begin(), someDataContainer.end(), 1);
```

Comment: It will return `someDataContainer.end()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The return value of `find` when the element is not present is the `end` iterator:

> [[alg.find](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.find)] (emphasis mine):
>
> Let E be:
>
> - `*i == value` for `find`,
> - [...]
>
> *Returns:* The first iterator `i` in the range `[first, last)` for which *E* is `true`. **Returns `last` if no such iterator is found**.

This includes the element not being present because the range is empty.

Answer (score 6):

An empty vector will have `begin() == end()` so `std::find` will just return immediately and return `end()`. No undefined behavior here.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter if the container is empty or not, the [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) will return the `end` iterator if the element is not found.

And in an empty container no element will be found.

In short: It's all well-defined and normal.

Answer (score 2):

It is documented on [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). If the the element cannot be found `last` is returned, i.e. in your case `it` will point to `someDataContainer.end()`.