# std::find behavior when std::vector is empty but given an initial size

Tags: c++11, stdvector

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54092408/does-stdfind-on-empty-vector-cause-undefined-behaviour#:%7E:text=An%20empty%20vector%20will%20have,No%20undefined%20behavior%20here.&text=It%20doesn%27t%20matter%20if,no%20element%20will%20be%20found.), `std::find` returns the `end` iterator when the container is empty. However, when I run this code with `gcc (GCC) 11.2.1 20220127 (Red Hat 11.2.1-9)`

```cpp
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>

    int getIndex(std::vector<int> v, int K)
    {
        auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), K);
        int index = -1;
        // If element was found
        if (it != v.end()) {
            index = it - v.begin();
        }

        return index;
    }

    int main()
    {
        std::vector<int> map_rows(10);
        for (int ii = 0; ii<5; ii++)
        {
            auto idx = getIndex(map_rows,ii);
            std::cout<<"ii: "<<ii<<", idx: "<<idx<<std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I get

```
ii: 0, idx: 0
ii: 1, idx: -1
ii: 2, idx: -1
ii: 3, idx: -1
ii: 4, idx: -1
```

This happens because I am initializing the vector with the size I need. However, the vector is empty (or so I thought, since I have not pushed any value into it). When instead I use

```cpp
std::vector<int> map_rows;
```

I get

```
ii: 0, idx: -1
ii: 1, idx: -1
ii: 2, idx: -1
ii: 3, idx: -1
ii: 4, idx: -1
```

I want to initialize the vector size since it might be large. Does anyone have an explanation?

**EDIT:**

Looks like the way to go, in my case is use `reserve` as in this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int getIndex(std::vector<int> v, int K)
{
    auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), K);
    int index = -1;
    // If element was found
    if (it != v.end() ){
        index = it - v.begin();
        // std::cout<<"*it: "<<*it<<std::endl;
        // index = std::distance(v.begin(), it);
    }

    return index;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> map_rows;
    map_rows.reserve(10);
    for (int ii = 0; ii<5; ii++)
    {
        std::cout<<"map_rows empty?: "<<map_rows.empty()<<std::endl;
        auto idx = getIndex(map_rows,ii);
        std::cout<<"ii: "<<ii<<", idx: "<<idx<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, this is a kind of odd behavior because to me the size should be zero when `std::vector` is given an initial size. If someone want to explain/elaborate, I will be very grateful.

Comment: `std::vector<int> map_rows(10);` is not an empty vector. It is a vector with 10 elements that are default initialized. For a vector of int that's 10 zeroes.

Comment: "to me the size should be zero when std::vector is given an initial size" Why? If you create a vector of a particular size that is what you get. If you want an empty vector then create one. If you want an empty vector but you want to reserve some memory to be used as the vector grows then do that.

Comment: oh! I thought it just reserved the memory but not actually create the objects. You learn everyday. So, initializing this way is not efficient in case it is not ints.  Let' say it is a vector of custom objects.  the constructor will be called 2 times. Once with the default object and then with the one we need to create and push.

Comment: @CaribeGirl If you initialize the `vector` to have 10 elements and then push, you are adding element 11 etc, so yes, it's efficient to create it with 10 elements if you want 10 elements to start with. If you know that you want X number of additional elements, you can use `reserve(vec.size() + X)` to make pushing/emplacing efficient.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes you are right, I wrote push, so your comment is correct. But I was thinking more, I used to init vectors this way assuming I was doing what `reserve()` does. Then loop and fill the `vec[ii]=new_object(blah), ii = 0,..,9`.  I was just realizing this is not efficient for non-basic types.

Comment: @CaribeGirl Ah, I see. Well, even for non-trivial types, they are usually _pretty_ cheap to construct and move-assign to, so I wouldn't think to much about the performance and go for simplicity to start with - until profiling your code shows that it's actually creating these vectors with a default-inserted value that is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

> However, the vector is empty (or so I thought, since I have not pushed any value into it)

You are using [this constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```
constexpr explicit vector( size_type count,
                           const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

This *"Constructs the container with `count` default-inserted instances of `T`"* - so the `vector` will not be empty. It will have exactly `10` default-inserted instances of `int`.

If you on the other hand use

```cpp
std::vector<int> map_rows;
map_rows.reserve(10);
```

it *will* be empty but will have reserved space for `10` `int`s which means that you can insert at least 10 elements before the `vector` needs to allocate a bigger chunk of memory and move all the elements to that memory area.

> this is a kind of odd behavior because to me the size should be zero when `std::vector` is given an initial size.

For most people it would come as a surprise if one created it an initial size of 10 but it was in fact created with a size of 0.

Comment: Thank you for helping me clear this out :). I hope your answer will help other confused souls like I was.